# Does python-pptx support saving a file as pdf?

Tags: python, linux, pdf-generation, powerpoint, python-pptx

I am playing a[round with python-pptx here](https://python-pptx.readthedocs.org/en/latest/user/quickstart.html) but I need to also save as pdf and I don't seem to see that this library support this feature.

Does anyone have a suggestion (either within this library or an external solution) to create a pptx file but also have the option to save as pdf.

Comment: Python-pptx will only work in creating Powerpoint slides. You can use `PDFMiner` or `PyPDF2` for creating `PDF's`. Cant think of any module that does both

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`python-pptx` doesn't support saving as PDF and it's very unlikely it ever will. The reason is that saving as a PDF involves rendering the PowerPoint file (.pptx) and the focus of `python-pptx` is on reading and writing the .pptx file format.

The scope of developing a faithful rendering engine for PowerPoint is both large and almost completely orthogonal to the file read/write problem.

The main rendering engine for PowerPoint is, well, PowerPoint :) The (Microsoft) PowerPoint API is accessible via IronPython on a Windows machine that has PowerPoint installed. It's not suitable for everything, for example it's not a good solution for server-side work, but if your project is small scale and you're already running on Windows it can be a good solution. I use it myself in the development of `python-pptx` (I'm the main author) for certain types of testing.

There are other rendering libraries out there, but I don't know of any open source ones. The one I've seen is a pay-for-license package. I'm sure there must be others because applications like GitHub for Mac and Box have fairly good previewing capability. I can't imagine they wrote that from scratch :)

Sorry I didn't have better news for you :)

Comment: thanks.  The reason I asked is that a few ppt export libraries in C# and java also support "save as pdf" like this one: http://www.aspose.com/.net/powerpoint-component.aspx

Answer (score 2):

I've had success using [unoconv](https://github.com/dagwieers/unoconv%20unoconv). However, it is not perfect - it uses LibreOffice to render your file, so things might look different than expected.